# How can I use serialized data in Gutenberg?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, serialization, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a Sidebar plugin that stores post meta to be used on the front end. Without getting into the unnecessary details, **I need to store all the data as 1 meta entry instead of many rows per post**. Here is what I have so far:

```
// ds-jars.js

const pluginContent = (props) => {

    const productData = () => {
        const categoryId = createElement( PanelRow, null, 
            createElement(TextControl, {
                label: "Category Name",
                value: props.category_id,
                onChange: (content) => {
                    props.set_category_id(content)
                },
            })
        )
        const serialId = createElement( PanelRow, null, 
            createElement( TextControl, {
                label: "Serial Number",
                value: props.serial_id,
                onChange: (content) => { 
                    props.set_serial_id(content)
                }
            })
        )
        const productId = createElement( PanelRow, null, 
            createElement( TextControl, {
                label: "Product ID",
                value: props.product_id,
                onChange: (content) => { 
                    props.set_product_id(content)
                }
            })
        )

        return createElement(PluginDocumentSettingPanel, {
            title: "Product Data",
            name: "ds-jars-productdata",
            icon: 'none',
        }, categoryId, serialId, productId
        )
    }

    return productData()
}

const selectData = (select) => {
    return { 
        category_id:        select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["category_id"],
        serial_id:          select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["serial_id"],
        product_id:         select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["product_id"],
        name:               select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["name"],
        quantity:           select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["quantity"],
        color:              select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["color"],
        height:             select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["height"],
        width:              select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["width"],
        depth:              select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["depth"],
        pattern:            select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["pattern"],
        date_made:          select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["date_made"],
        date_updated:       select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["date_updated"],
        date_expired:       select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["date_expired"]
    }
}

const dispatchData = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        set_category_id:    (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{category_id: value} })},
        set_serial_id:      (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{serial_id: value} })},
        set_product_id:     (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{product_id: value} })},
        set_name:           (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{name: value} })},
        set_quantity:       (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{quantity: value} })},
        set_color:          (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{color: value} })},
        set_height:         (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{height: value} })},
        set_width:          (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{width: value} })},
        set_depth:          (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{depth: value} })},
        set_pattern:        (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{pattern: value} })},
        set_date_made:      (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{date_made: value} })},
        set_date_updated:   (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{date_updated: value} })},
        set_date_expired:   (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{date_expired: value} })}
    }
}

let fieldSelect = withSelect(selectData)(pluginContent)
let fieldDispatch = withDispatch(dispatchData)(fieldSelect)

registerPlugin( "ds-jars", {
    icon: 'store',
    render: fieldDispatch 
})
```

Obviously this works but saves each field as its own meta row entry. According to this post: [WP 5.3 Supports Object and Array Meta Types in the REST API](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/03/wp-5-3-supports-object-and-array-meta-types-in-the-rest-api/). I should be able to send an object to the meta field by using an array in for "show_in_rest". I have been able to register the field I want properly using the following:

```
register_post_meta('', 'ds_product', 
            array(
                'type' => 'object',
                'single' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => array(
                    'schema' => array(
                        'type' => 'object',
                        'properties' => array(
                            'category_id'   => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'serial_id'     => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'product_id'    => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'name'          => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'quantity'      => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'color'         => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'height'        => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'width'         => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'depth'         => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'pattern'       => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'date_made'     => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'date_updated'  => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'date_expired'  => array('type' => 'string'),
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

I am able to manually send an object through with console.log so it seems it is ready for my values to be sent to it as an object. **The problem I am having is writing/reading to this meta field using the withSelect/withDispatch functions. How can I send all my values to this meta field "ds_product" using withDispatch?** Been struggling with this for a week. I have tried many things the closest I got was using

```
// Create prop to get data from serialized field
category_id: select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["ds_product"].category_id
category_id: select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")["ds_product"].serial_id
...

// Update serialized field
set_category_id: (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{ds_product:{category_id: value} }})},
set_serial_id: (value) => {dispatch("core/editor").editPost({meta:{ds_product:{serial_id: value} }})},
...
```

Since they update one at a time the field ends up storing the previously changed value only thus wiping all other data before it. Any help would be hugely appreciated. As a final note I am aware of the dangers/limitations of storing serialized data to the database but I still need it to be done this way. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and what has worked for me is the following usage of `dispatch()` and `saveEntityRecord`.

In the following example I am saving a serialized object to the `wp_options` table in the WP database.

```js
// Save serialized data to wp_options.
dispatch('core').saveEntityRecord('root', 'site', {
    my_plugin_settings: {
      test_1: 'Test 1 Setting Value',
      test_2: 'Test 1 Setting Value',
    },
  }).then(() => {

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    dispatch('core/notices').createErrorNotice('Error', {
      isDismissible: true,
      type: 'snackbar',
    });
  });
});
```

First, you have to register the settings like you have above so it's available over the REST API.

```php
register_setting(
        'my_plugin_settings',
        'my_plugin_settings',
        [
            'default'      => '',
            'show_in_rest' => [
                'schema' => [
                    'type'       => 'object',
                    'properties' => [
                        'test_1' => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                        'test_2'                 => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Then using the code in my answer above you can save the serialized value properly.